# Add server to farm - missing patch / different versions numbers on the same update

Tags: 2013, central-administration, patching, update

I was going to add a new server to our SharePoint farm today to scale out the search service application to it's own server. Installing prerequisites, installing SharePoint 2013 - everything went on just flawless.

Time to connect the new server to the farm. Loads of patches missing locally on the new server. Sure, no big deal. Downloaded each one of them manually and applied to the new server. Every error goes away.

Almost every error. From the KB update "KB2889937" I got a newer version of the update, while the rest of the existing farm runs the same update with an older version number.

Where do I go from here?

The only thing I can think of is to try to apply the newer version of the same update to the rest of the farm, but I'm unsure if the server will accept it as the same KB number are already installed? Or is there anywhere where Microsoft keep old updates for download?

The servernames are figurated.

[image]

Comment: did you try to re apply the patch kb2889937? what is the outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this exact issue today with KB2889937 which I resolved by completing the following:

- Download the executable for KB2889937 from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2889937
- Ensure you have a full backup of the farm including server snapshots just in case!
- Run the EXE for KB2889937 on each server in the farm. For those where it is already installed and not required you will receive a warning that the patch does not affect any products installed on the server.
- Chances are one of the servers in the farm is missing the binaries and will install. It will take around 30-45 minutes to install.
- Once complete open The SharePoint Management Shell on every farm server and run this cmdlet **get-spproduct -local**. It will verify the patch status of each server.
- Once the above cmdlet has been run on all farm servers go back to Central Administration and under "servers in farm" you should no longer see "installation required" but instead "upgrade required".
- Schedule a maintenance window, reboot each farm server and then run the Products and Configuration Wizard on each server to upgrade remembering to upgrade the farm server hosting Central Administration first. Doing a reboot and ensuring CA is upgraded first gives you a greater probability of success in my experience!

Lee

Comment: Thanks for answering Lee, if i remember it correct this was just what we did to solve it. :) Get-spproduct -local is a lifesaver..

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced similar behaviors with different patches on SharePoint 2010 farms. In those cases, I reapplied the same patch on the servers.

I think you should examine this post:
http://www.benstegink.com/sharepoint-2013-october-2014-updates-build-numbers/

The post lists build numbers and corresponding KB numbers that match your screenshot.  You could use the information in the post to track down the patches you need and apply them until you match your servers.

In addition, note that it is possible you already have the patch(s) via Windows Updates.  I mention this because recently I experienced mismatches on a farm I hadn't manually patched in a while.  The problem stemmed from SharePoint updates coming through Windows Updates that failed on one of the farm servers.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below, i see it was helpful to most users.

https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/psconfig-fails-with-missing-required-error-message-after-applying-cu-or-service-pack-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Please add some details from the link.